# Users table - redis or postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, redis, storage

Redis persists data and works on key value stores with a great feature called Hashsets.

Should redis be used to store information like 'customer, user, product, order' or is this the job of a relational database?

Comment: It all depends on what your needs are.  Based on your question there is no reason to think PostgreSQL wouldn't work just fine or any other rdms that's been around for the last 20+ years.

Comment: I come from a relational db background so postgres/ sql sever are obvious choices. But is redis a better option? What is the argument for using redis and the argument for using postgres (not a debate, simply bullet pointed benefits and constraints) - i think the answer to this would accurately answer my initial question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data requires relations and you don't need to cache it for performance reasons then PostgreSQL will probably suite you more. Redis is mostly used for it's speed capabilities and support for advanced (mostly key-value based) data structures, but RDBMS like Postgres are better to use for scenarios with relationships and ACID requirements.